# How to remove a nested dependency in pnpm

Tags: javascript, node-modules, package.json, package-managers, pnpm

For example in my project I include [`svgo`](https://github.com/svg/svgo/blob/main/package.json) which has a deprecated dependency `stable` which results into warning during installation:

```
 WARN  deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
```

I can remove this package from source code of `svgo` via `pnpm patch`, but how to also exclude it from package resolution to avoid PNPM WARN?

If I manually remove `stable` package from lock file, it will appear again after using `pnpm update`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `svgo` will fail without `stable`

If you remove `stable`, `svgo` won't run, because it [uses stable](https://github.com/svg/svgo/blob/dfc5b982c952094ed07dcaebcf04a5ac00052bc8/lib/style.js#L16).

## Fork instead

Instead, you should fork the package make the necessary code changes to `svgo`, then use your modified. Thanksfully, [people on the internets](https://github.com/svg/svgo/pull/1681) have already [done this for you](https://github.com/boidolr/svgo/tree/remove-stable).

All you need to do is

```
npm i boidolr/svgo#remove-stable
```

This should replace `svgo` with the edited version that has no `stable`.

Comment: I know it uses stable. As I said, I've already removed it from svgo via `pnpm patch`. Just curious if I can also remove this dependency from package resolution. Since there is already a fork online, I can also override `svgo` with this fork. Thanks

Comment: @YueJIN it seens strange that PNPM does not allow patching `package.json`. There is a package called [`patch-package`](https://github.com/nathanlisch/patch-package-with-pnpm-support), but this also does not seem to allow patching `package.json`. I guess this makes sense, since a patch to `package.json` would have to be applied by the package manager *before* it resolves and installs dependencies and before running post-install scripts, then it would have to apply patches again after post-install script. I think manual change is only way to go in this case